# Displaying array values in Bar chart of HighCharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to display values which I am getting dynamically. In the below code I am trying to store the values in array and I am trying to use the array values in "series: data".
Nothing is getting displayed in the graph. 
I know this is very simple question but I did not get any satisfactory answer when I googled it. Please help

```
var x = window.location.search.replace( "?", "" );
        x = x.substring(3);
        var array = x.split(",");  // I am storing my dynamic values in  this array


$(function () {
        //alert(array);   ----- I am able to see the values here 
        $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'bar'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Wireless Experience Meter'
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: 'Sub - Time to Download'
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: ['Text'],
                title: {
                    text: null
                }
            },
            yAxis: {
                min: 0,
                title: {
                    text: 'Time (ms)',
                    align: 'high'
                },
                labels: {
                    overflow: 'justify'
                }
            },
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: ' ms'
            },
            plotOptions: {
                bar: {
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true
                    }
                }
            },
            legend: {
                layout: 'vertical',
                align: 'right',
                verticalAlign: 'top',
                x: -40,
                y: 100,
                floating: true,
                borderWidth: 1,
                backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
                shadow: true
            },
            credits: {
                enabled: false
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Attempt 1',
                //data: [635, 203, 200] 
                data : [array[0]]   // I need to pass the variables here to get it displayed 
            }, {
                name: 'Attempt 2',
                //data: [133, 408, 698]
                data : [array[1]]
            }, {
                name: 'Attempt 3',
                //data: [973, 914, 4054]
                data : [array[2]]
            }]
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't tell us what the variable `array` equals but since its generated from `x.split(",")`, it's elements are going to be strings and not the numeric values Highcharts needs.

So convert it with `parseInt` or `parseFloat`:

```
var numericData = [];
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
   numericData.push(parseFloat(array[i]));
}
...
series: [{
   name: 'Attempt 1',
   data : numericData 
},
...
```

Answer (score 0):

`[array[0]]` is not an array, that looks like `console` output not javascript.  But `[[0]]` or `[0]` technically would be.  However, since a call to array (`array(0)`) generates an array then I think you want `data: array(0)`.

Outside shot at `data : [array(0)]`   if you didn't show the example data correctly. I've never used HighCharts so I don't know what it's expected but I still go with `data : array(0)`